# Why the need for explicit conversion of Struct element if it is already stored with that type?

Tags: solidity

If we have the following struct and array:

```
struct Family {                               
  bytes32 lastName;                               
  uint8 houseNo;                               
  uint16 age;                           
}

Family[] myFamily;
```

And the following function:

```
function getName(bytes32 name) public view returns (bytes32, uint8, uint16) {
  for(uint8 i = 0; i < myFamily.length; i++){
    if(name == myFamily[i].lastName) {
      return (myFamily[i].lastName,uint8(myFamily[i].houseNo), myFamily[i].age);
    }
  }
}
```

Why the need for explicit conversion of `uint8(myFamily[i].houseNo)` in the return? Isn't it already stored as `uint8`?

Comment: What makes you think that there is such a need?

Comment: With solidity 0.4.25, there is definitely no need. You might want to share with us which compiler version requires you to do that conversion explicitly.

Comment: You're right, it compiles with success. I was using version >= 0.5.

Comment: You still haven't answered the question!

Comment: I saw it in a tutorial and took it for granted. I've tested it now and realized there is no issue and the conversion isn't needed. Should I remove the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not needed.

All recent versions of solc 0.4.26, 0.5.16 and 0.6.1 will accept the code without the convertion.

```
function getName(bytes32 name) public view returns (bytes32, uint8, uint16) {
  for(uint8 i = 0; i < myFamily.length; i++){
    if(name == myFamily[i].lastName) {
      return (myFamily[i].lastName, myFamily[i].houseNo, myFamily[i].age);
    }
  }
}
```

It is very easy to try a snippet of code in remix.ethereum.org against different versions of solc.